# How to divide using php

Tags: php, division

How do you divide in php ?
When I look online it says use a '/' yet this does not work? 
When I run the same code with a * for multiply it works.

```
$timesby = 360 / 36;
```

Why is this?
Is there a different symbol?

Thanks

Comment: How does this not work? How did you inspect the result of this operation?

Comment: @justinelejeune [Why not?](http://3v4l.org/s70AV)

Comment: looks fine to me, what is the result?

Comment: all working now. Still unsure of why it wasn't working and now is. But its working now thanks for such quick replies

Comment: If this is all that you have in your code, it might just be that you're not using the `<?php` opening tag, or that php is improperly installed. In both cases it would give different output, maybe try elaborating your question some more?

Comment: it was for populating a pie chart the full variables code was $total = ($pass1 + $pass2); $timesby = 360 / ($total); $actualpass1 = ($timesby) * $pass1; I needed that to work to populate a pie chart and now it does. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted is working just fine.

```
$timesby = 360 / 36;
echo($timesby);
> 10
```

In PHP, division is done using the / operator, just as you have done above.

Answer (score 2):

The code posted is the correct way to do division in PHP. For more information, refer to the PHP.net docs on [Arithmetic operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
<?php
echo 360 / 36; // Prints 10
echo 10 / 5; // Prints 2
echo 10 / 3; // Prints 3.3333333333333
```